# Xamarin VS2019 Emulator pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28 cannot be started

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I am getting this error when trying to debug a project in Xamarin C#

I literally just created a new project and chose the latest SDK and hit accept on a lot of popups, I did not type in any code yet

```
Emulator pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28 cannot be started
```

I have the following settings selected under Android SDK:
But I dont understand this menu at all, why are all my options using Atom processor?
What devices still use Atom processors? Im trying to build an App to run on an Arm Android Phone
Is there any cross compilation happening? Is this referring to the processor I am on (Intel i5, not atom) or the processor its targeting. This is so needlessly confusing

[image]

Comment: Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows Make sure to have Virtualization enabled in your BIOS/UEFI. Make sure to enable either Windows Hypervisor Platform _or_ Intel HAXM.

Comment: Before debugging, be sure that your android emulator is up and running. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> why are all my options using Atom processor? What devices still use Atom processors? Im trying to build an App to run on an Arm Android Phone Is there any cross compilation happening? Is this referring to the processor I am on (Intel i5, not atom) or the processor its targeting.

Android is based on the intel Atom (X86) virtual machine.**In short**, this virtual machine allows the Android emulator to run at the original speed (real machine running speed) in a computer using an Intel x86 processor.

**Therefore**, there is no need to tangle these options here. If want emulator to runs on PC, you need to select the **Intel x86 Atom System Image** or **Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image** at least.